# Linq to Xml query to child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<InventoryList>
 <Product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Name>Pizza Ristorante Hawaii</Name>
  <Price>2.99</Price>
  <VariableWeightPrice>€ 8,42 / kg</VariableWeightPrice>
  <Brand>Dr.Oetker</Brand>
  <PackageInfo>355 GR</PackageInfo>
  <categoryString />
  <PictureSmallFilename>1small.jpg</PictureSmallFilename>
  <InformationTakenFrom>Jumbo</InformationTakenFrom>
  <MarketItemUrl></MarketItemUrl>
  <BarCode>4001724819608</BarCode>
  <IsBlackListed>false</IsBlackListed>
  <ItemLists>
    <Item>
        <ListName>in</ListName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <QuantityWeight>0</QuantityWeight>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ListName>out</ListName>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <QuantityWeight>0</QuantityWeight>
    </Item>
  </ItemLists>
 </Product>
 <Product xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>2</Id>
  <Name>Produto 2</Name>
  <Price>2.99</Price>
  <VariableWeightPrice>€ 5,55 / kg</VariableWeightPrice>
  <Brand>Dr.Oetker</Brand>
  <PackageInfo>355 GR</PackageInfo>
  <categoryString />
  <PictureSmallFilename>1small.jpg</PictureSmallFilename>
  <InformationTakenFrom>Jumbo</InformationTakenFrom>
  <MarketItemUrl></MarketItemUrl>
  <BarCode>4001724819608</BarCode>
  <IsBlackListed>false</IsBlackListed>
  <ItemLists>
    <Item>
        <ListName>out</ListName>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <QuantityWeight>0</QuantityWeight>
    </Item>
  </ItemLists>
</Product>
</InventoryList>
```

thanks in advance for your help.
I have this xml database

i want to return all products that have the ListName = "out", but this query i´m trying it´s only returning the second product, and i need it to return the first and the second product.

```
 var _queryItems = from c in xml.Descendants("Product")
                          where
                              c.Element("ItemLists").Element("Item").Element("ListName").Value == "out"
                          select c;
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you just check the first `Item` element, instead you want to check if *any* Item's `ListName` matches "out":

```
var _queryItems = from c in xml.Descendants("Product") 
                  where c.Element("ItemLists")
                         .Elements("Item").Any( x=> x.Element("ListName").Value == "out") 
                  select c;
```